# не получается корректно передать данные из обработчика форм через телеграм бота (Python django)

Tags: python

такая проблема.
Cоздал сайт , на котором есть поля ввода информации
изначально было 2 поля Имя и Телефон , все корректно обрабатывалось
решил добавить еще 3 поля , изменил обработчик форм , все вроде бы корректно работает , но не могу корректно захватить(считать) текст получаемый от пользователя использую:
'''

```
a = text.find("{")
b = text.find("}")
c = text.rfind("{")
d = text.rfind("}")
u = text.find("{")
p = text.rfind("}")

part_1 = text[0:a]
part_2 = text[b + 1:c]
part_3 = text[d + 1:u]
part_4 = text[p:-2]

text_message = part_1 + tg_name + part_2 + tg_phone + part_3 + tg_vacancy + part_4
```

'''
(решил добавлять по 1 полю и смотреть как выводится)
ожидаемый вывод :

```
Имя : { name }
Телефон : { phone }
Вакансия : { vacancy }
```

реальный вывод:

```
Имя : Иван
Телефон : { phone }
Вакансия : 89807664848Сушист
```

не могу понять почему так происходит
вероятно использую не правильно find , rfind и срезы

буду благодарен за помощь , простите если корявый вопрос (первый раз)